# Не могу понять принцип работы простейшей функции

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия

Здравствуйте! Я понимаю суть этого алгоритма, но я не могу разобраться почему если убрать в рекурсивной функции `return` перед `x`, то ответ становится неверным. Как в этом примере работает `return`, и почему без него не обойтись?

```
#include <iostream>

int fact(int x)    
{    
    if (x == 1) return 1;    
    return x * fact(x - 1);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << fact(5) << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: зачем вообще нужен `return` в этом языке программирования?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте уберём `return` перед `x`:

```
int fact(int x) {    
    if (x == 1)
        return 1;
    x * fact(x - 1);
}
```

Что тут у нас происходит:

- В начале функции выполняется проверка параметра функции `x` на равенство единице
- В случае равенства возвращается один, так как `1! = 1`
- В случае неравенства выполняется строчка `x * fact(x - 1);`

  - В этой строчке вычисляется произведение `x` и результата рекурсивного вызова функции
  - Так как мы убрали `return`, то оно не возвращается, просто вычислилось и функция продолжает выполняться
  - Код доходит до конца функции
  - Так как ни один `return` не был выполнен, то из функции вернётся какой-то мусор
  - Можно отлавливать такие ошибки на этапе компиляции, добавив флаг `-Wall`. Например, у меня при компиляции с этим флагом выводятся следующие предупреждения:

    ```
    % g++ -Wall main.cpp
    main.cpp: В функции «int fact(int)»:
    main.cpp:6:7: предупреждение: вычисленное значение не используется [-Wunused-value]
         x * fact(x - 1);
         ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    main.cpp:7:1: предупреждение: управление достигает конца не-void функции [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
    ```

Comment: Спасибо огромное,вы мне очень помогли)

Comment: @Abyx, да, надо было лучше про UB написать чем про всё остальное... Грустно.

Comment: @Abyx: верно: *"Flowing  off  the  end  of  a
  function  is  equivalent  to  a  return with no value; this results in
  undefined behavior in a value-returning function."* [n2356 (c++98) §6.6.3.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/stmt.html)